# jquery mobile append button not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I dynamically add a li that contains a button, the button renders correctly when I add it like this:

```
$($ul).append( $li ).trigger('create');
$($ul).listview( "refresh" );
$($ul).trigger( "updatelayout" );
```

But I need to add the li with the button after the first item in the ul.  This adds the li in the correct position but the button does not render correctly.

```
$($ul).eq(0).after($( $li )).trigger('create');
$($ul).listview( "refresh" );
$($ul).trigger( "updatelayout" );
```

I completely stumped and would appreciate any suggestions!!!

Clarify my question(hopefully this helps):
Why does the button render correctly when I just append the li and not correctly when I try to add the li to a certain position in the ul?

Here is the html of the button after it gets inserted:

```
<button class="deleteLiRadio" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete">Button</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't render correctly?

Comment: The button renders as a normal html button when it should render as a single jquery mobile X that they provide as a png.

Comment: it looks to me like the li is being injected outside the ul possibly which would mess up its style rules.  can you inspect it using a simulator and verify the html

Comment: @Rooster I put the html above.

Comment: no I mean are you sure the li is being inserted into the ul properly and not outside it

Comment: @Rooster Yes, it's within the ul tags.

Comment: Is it a split button? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Rooster it seems to be completely ignoring the data-iconpos="notext"  and data-icon="delete".

Comment: @Adam probably because of that empty data- tag  or space between data-shadow you have in the middle of the button code

Comment: @Omar It's not a split button.  A fiddle would take me a bit.

Comment: @Rooster Sorry, the data- space was a typo.  It's correct in the code.

Comment: @Adam try this

    $($ul).find('li:first-child').after($( $li )).trigger('create');

instead of:

    $($ul).eq(0).after($( $li )).trigger('create');

Comment: @Rooster Good thought, but did not work.  I think is has something to do with it not getting refreshed and updatelayout properly.

Comment: Ah sorry. I don't think I can help more without a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are actually adding the `li` outside of the `ul`.

Instead of `$($ul).eq(0)` it should be  `$ul.find('li')`

For example the following code should do what you want

```
  var $ul = $('#myList');
    var $li = $('<li><button class="deleteLiRadio" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete">Button</button></li>');
    $ul.find('li').eq(0).after($li);
    $ul.trigger('create').listview( "refresh" );
    $ul.trigger( "updatelayout" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rbAc9/1/

Comment: YOU'RE THE BEST.  Much appreciated!!! Worked Perfectly, if you could'nt already tell by my all caps and exclamation marks.

Comment: Well, I got you back to zero.  Cheers!